# What does this do: name =~ /family/i

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm just assuming based on the context of where I got it that its some form of regular expression that returns a boolean based on wether or not the string includes the characters between / /

But is there more to it?  Is there a name for this sort of thing so I can google it?

Comment: [`=~`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-3D-7E) is a method on the String class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assumption is correct. In this particular case this is a check to see if the string contains the word "family" and is case-insensitive due to the trailing `i`

It doesn't return a boolean though. Instead, it returns the position in the string where the first match occurred.

Here's an example:

```
irb(main):001:0> name = "my Family"
=> "my Family"
irb(main):002:0> name =~ /family/i
=> 3
```

You can learn much more details by reading [Ruby's documentation for the string class](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-3D-7E).

Answer (score 0):

It checks to see if the variable `name` matches the regular expression `/family/i`

The `i` makes the regex case-insensitive, so `FaMilY` would match.